Uploading to AWS on ExpressJS takes a very long time when it is deployed on the server
I uploaded a file to AWS S3 with ExpressJS, but the upload time is very long about 15 seconds and above for a photo size of about 1MB. How to optimize / speed up the upload time
My program is as below:
const { S3Client, PutObjectCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-s3");

const s3Client = new S3Client({
    region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
    credentials: {
        accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    }
});

module.exports = {

    createAplikasietcs: async (req, res) => {
        try {

            const schema = {
                name: { type: "string", min: 3 },
                image: {
                    type: "string",
                    optional: true
                }            
            }

            if (req.file) {
                const timestamp = new Date().getTime();
                const uniqueFileName = `${timestamp}-${req.file.originalname}`;

                const uploadParams = {
                    Bucket: process.env.AWS_S3_BUCKET,
                    Key: `dir_mpp/aplikasietc/${uniqueFileName}`,
                    Body: req.file.buffer,
                    ACL: 'public-read',
                    ContentType: req.file.mimetype,
                };

                const command = new PutObjectCommand(uploadParams);

                await s3Client.send(command);

                imageKey = `https://${process.env.AWS_S3_BUCKET}.s3.${process.env.AWS_REGION}.amazonaws.com/${uploadParams.Key}`;
            }

            let AplikasietcsCreateObj = {
                name: req.body.name,
                image: req.file ? imageKey : undefined,
            }

            const validate = v.validate(AplikasietcsCreateObj, schema);
            if (validate.length > 0) {
                res.status(400).json(response(400, 'validation failed', validate));
                return;
            }

            let AplikasietcsCreate = await Aplikasietcs.create(AplikasietcsCreateObj);
            res.status(201).json(response(201, 'success create', AplikasietcsCreate));
        } catch (err) {
            res.status(500).json(response(500, 'internal server error', err));
            console.log(err);
        }
    }

I wish the photo upload time was faster, about 3-5 seconds
